# Return a promise without waiting for a dependant promise in function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am using node 8.x. Hence, I have access to all latest features i.e. async/ await etc.

The scenario is similar to following 
(Not correct syntax, just for explanation):

```
createUser()
{
    let userAddress = createAddress(); // Aync, returns a promise
    User.create(name: 'foo', address: userAddress); // User creation is dependant on address. Also, User.create returns a promise.
}
```

Basically, User object creation is dependant on the creation of address object. I want the createUser function to execute asynchronously i.e. to return a promise as soon as possible without waiting for address object to be created.

The purpose of this question is not to get things done but to understand what is the best way to solve this kind of issues in async programming.

Few ways that I can think of:
1: Create a new promise object and return right away when entered in createUser function. Resolve it when the user object is created.
2: Make createUser an async function and then return user Promise. Facing issues with this method:

```
async function createUser()
{
    address = await createAddress();
    return User.create(name: 'foo', address: userAddress);
}
```

The problem is function waits for the address before returning the control which I don't want. (Or it does not make any diff as the function is async. Performance is a big criterion in my case)

How to deal with this kind of promise dependancy where you want to return promise of parent object but you parent object is dependant on child object's promise.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question ... you want to return `User.create` (promise) before `createAddress` is complete, but `User.create` depends on `createAddress`.

Comment: Yes. I don't want the function to wait for the address. Whenever the address is created, the user should get created and hence, the promise should get resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make createUser an async function and then return user Promise. The problem is function waits for the address before returning the control which I don't want.

No, it doesn't. An `async function` does immediately return a promise to its caller. It waits only when executing the code in its body (and resolves the promise when you `return`). Your code works, this is exactly what you should be doing.

Comment: Thanks. But if I debug or print to console I see that it definitely does not wait for the address to get created(you are right) but the
- the control enters the createUser
- then it enters the createAddress() as well which returns a promise
- then the control returns back to place from where the createUser function was called.
So the async function does not return a promise right away. Or am I still missing something?

Comment: @AakashMalhotra Ah, yes, everything until the first `await` (i.e. the `createAddress` call and promise creation) are happening synchronously. Only then `createUser` returns its promise to the caller - but it's still *immediate*, not waiting for any promise to fulfill.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your function as-is and then it depends on how it's called. You can't use `await` because that blocks in the current scope. You can introduce a new scope using `.then`, though:

```
async function createUser() {
  address = await createAddress();
  return User.create({ name: 'foo', address });
}
...
createUser().then(() => { /* handle user creation */ });
// code here will not wait for `createUser` to finish
```

Answer (score 0):

If `createAddress` is a promise returning the address, let's say `address`, you can do something like this:

```
createAddress().then(function(address) {
  User.create(name: 'foo', address: address).then(function() {
    // User and address has been created
  })
})

// Do something here that runs even though createAddress has not yet been resolved
```

This will require you to wait for the promise to be resolved before doing some other code.

Comment: A `then()` inside another `then()` ... is this correct?

Comment: @robe007 yes it is

Comment: Why not? It's basically just a pretty abstraction on top of callbacks.

Comment: @AakashMalhotra I said because -for me- that is called _nested promises_, I think is sufficient with one `then()`: `function createUser(){
    return createAddress().then(function(address) {
        return User.create(name: 'foo', address: address) // the return is to handle latter the user creation
    }, function() {
        throw 'Promise Rejected';
    });
}`

Comment: You could do it like that. Both approaches are doing the same thing, i.e. chaining promises. Promise > then > then.

Comment: @feupeu Yes I know, but I'm talking about `patterns, best practices, avoid anti-patterns`; and _chaining promises_ has their [owns](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a promise, then you're basically looking to use promises the way they were intended to be used:

```
createUser() {
    return createAddress()
        .then((address) =>
            User.create({ name: 'foo', address: address })
        );
}
```

Now the `createUser` method is returning a promise, which will be resolved at some point in the future. Your code can continue work, can add more `.then(...)` or `.catch(...)` callbacks to that promise, etc.

Comment: Is promise returned by createAddress function getting resolved in createUser function itself and is the promise returned by createUser() the promise actually returned by User.create ?

Comment: Shouldn't there be 'return' keyword before 'User.create' function?

Comment: The promise is getting resolved whenever `createAddress` resolves it - I don't have the details of that function, so I don't know when it gets resolved. As for your second comment, that's the ES6 "fat arrow" syntax - see [this link](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html#sec_arrow-function-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach, assuming that `createAddress` returns a promise (of course)

```
function createUser(){
    return createAddress().then(function(address) {
        // the return is to handle latter the user creation
        return User.create(name: 'foo', address: address)
    }, function() {
        throw 'Promise Rejected';
    });
}

createUser().then(function(result) {
    console.log("result => " + result);
    // Do something here with the 'user creation' if you want
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("error => " + error);
});

// Do some stuff, while the code above is executed
```

Comment: Isn't this just what @Kryten already posted? (Plus that superfluous `throw`)

Comment: It's my answer !